# "Respect, where has it gone?" vs "Respect. Where has it gone?"

Tags: punctuation, orthography

We are using the following topic for a speech contest and there is a question as to punctuation

> Respect, where has it gone?

or

> Respect. Where has it gone?

Comment: Pick a random one. That one is correct.

Answer (score 4):

I would go with *Respect: Where Has It Gone?*, where the colon represents that what goes before it is the topic of what comes after.